# Why cant http.get work with strings anymore?

Tags: flutter, dart, uri, httpresponse

I was trying to get information from an API endpoint by using:

```
Response response= await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
```

but this didnt work so I had to parse it using Uri:

```
Response response= await get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'));
```

Why do we need to use Uri to parse the HTTP address?

Comment: Previously `http.get` (and various other functions) accepted either a `String` or a `Uri` argument.  That required taking that argument as a `dynamic` type, but that also meant that *any* argument could passed without compilation errors, so things such as `http.get(123)`, `http.get(true)`, `http.get(null)` would crashes that wouldn't be caught until runtime.

Answer (score 0):

`Uri.parse` method validates the provided URL.
If the provided URL is not valid, you see exception in console

Flutter team says:

> If start and end are provided, they must specify a valid substring of
> uri, and only the substring from start to end is parsed as a URI. If
> the uri string is not valid as a URI or URI reference, a
> FormatException is thrown.
> You can learn more [from here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Uri/parse.html)

Surely, `Uri.parse` method is most powerful than sending request to server before validation the URL